# How to send using STOMP client to Spring Controller and then redirect to a new route?

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

This is what I am trying to do:
1) I first retrieve login.jsp file using the root route. 
2) When the form in login.jsp is submitted, 
a) I am using SockJS & WebSocket over STOMP to  connect to the WebSocket endpoint, 
b) Using the Stomp client to send the username to the /login route
c) Once the /login route stores the username in an HttPSession, it should redirect to /chat - the redirect is not working.

login.jsp - This contains the form that user will submit:

```html
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="connect">
    </form>
```

My Spring Controller message handlers

```
//Stores the username received from the form in a session
@MessageMapping("/login")
@SendTo("/topic/users")
@RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(String username,HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("username", username);
    return "redirect:/chat"; //redirect not working
}



@RequestMapping("/chat")
public String chat(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    String username = (String) session.getAttribute("username");
    model.addAttribute("username", username);
    return "chat.jsp";
}
```

My app.js

```
var stompClient = null;


$(function () {
    $("form").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $( "#connect" ).click(function() { connect(); });
});


function connect(){
    var socket = new SockJS('/ws-chat');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({},function(frame){
        console.log("SockJS Connected");
        stompClient.subscribe("/topic/users",function(){
            stompClient.send("/app/login",{},JSON.stringify({'username':$('#username').val()}));

        })
    });
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information to answer you, Please provide more. what is the path `/action` doing for example?

Comment: Updated the post on what I am trying to accomplish